# How to read request body that contain Chinese characters in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I use postman to call my API with request body like below (I send it as text/plain).

```json
{
  name: "Hello 你好",
  list: []
}
```

My FastAPI setup

```py
@app.post("/test")
async def test(
    data: Request
):
    text = await data.body()
    print(text)
    return True
```

Then, I log the data in my API server (Python FastAPI). I got this `b'{"name":"Hello \xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd","data":[]}'`. But I want `b'{"name":"Hello 你好","data":[]}'`. How to read the data properly?

Comment: Don't send it as text/plain (which doesn't include any information about the encoding) - instead use JSON (since that's what you're sending anyways) encoded as UTF-8 - and don't look at the binary representation - but the actual unicode text version.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get `b'{"name":"Hello 你好","data":[]}'` This is because the representation of the string object that you are printing is the `byte` representation. For more information on the difference between objects of type `str` or `byte`, read [here](https://diveintopython3.net/strings.html). Assuming you are outputting the representation of the data to your terminal, you should try to extract the field (`name`) from the request body, and then try the following:

`print(data.name)`

If this happens to return the `byte` representation of the string, which is denoted by the character `b` appearing before it, as in `b'{"name":"Hello \xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd","data":[]}'`, try:

`print(str(data.name, 'utf-8'))`